# How do I integrate OAuth client authentication alongside Laravel standard authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, oauth, eloquent

I've been Googling for quite some time now for some ideas or a guide on how to integrate OAuth (v1.0 & v2.0) alongside the standard Laravel 4 Eloquent authentication driver.

Essentially, I'd like to be able for site visitors to create an account via their existing Google, Facebook, or Twitter accounts, or via the standard email/password authentication. Certain user information such as email, first and last names, and avatar are important for me to have stored in a unified `users` table.

So far the projects I've looked at seem to support only OAuth and do away with the standard method. These projects include: [eloquent-oauth](https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth), and [oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel).

At this point, I might just roll my own solution, but I'm hoping some of you guys might have better advice for me!

**TL;DR**: I'm stuck at trying to find a simple and secure way to allow OAuth and standard Eloquent user authentication in Laravel. Halp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use this service provider that you mention "artdarek/oauth-4-laravel" and then store the values as usual and log them in.

```
 /**
 * Login user with facebook
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function loginWithFacebook() {

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get( 'code' );

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken( $code );

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode( $fb->request( '/me' ), true );

        // store new user or login if user exists
        $validator = Validator::make($result, array(
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:users'
        ));

        if ($validator->passes()) {
            # Save user in DB
            $user = new User;
            $user->username = $result['name'];
            $user->email = $result['email'];
            $user->save();
        }else {
            $user = User::findByUsernameOrFail($result['name']);
        }

        Auth::login($user);

    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
         return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, that actually makes a lot of sense. For some reason I was thinking it had to be more complicated than that, i.e. service providers, separate tables, etc. Thanks!